# Run a linear regression that uses one column to predict the log of another column?

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I have this data:

```
        A     B
  1 632364    4
  2 144599    2
  3 3715821   2
  4 184524    5
  5 1674      11
  6 0         4
  7 8019      7
  8 25992     6
  9 0         16
 10 0         15
 11 19172040  2
```

I am trying run a linear regression on B to predict the log of A.

I tried doing this:

`B.lm <- lm(B ~ A) 
log.A <- as.data.frame(log(A)) 
predict(B.lm,log.A, interval="predict")`

what it gives me doesn't seem right.

Any ideas? Also not sure how to handle the log of zero

Comment: What results did you get? Why don't they seem right?

Comment: Don't you want to build the original model off of the `log(A)`, not `A`?  You might do something like (assuming you have a column called `logA` which is the `log(A)` value) `B.lm <- lm(B ~ logA)` then you could do your prediction.  The thing to keep in mind is that zero in the `A` column will become `Inf` when you take the log (you will have to deal with that).

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the 0 values so that log is meaningful.  The limitation is that the resulting model will never be able to predict a zero.  If the zeros really represent missing values and the missing values are missing at random then this may not matter.  The input `dd` is shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  The code below fits the model and then plots the points for which A > 0 and plots a line for the fitted (i.e. predicted) values.

```
ddpos <- subset(dd, A > 0)
fm <- lm(log(A) ~ B, ddpos)
plot(log(A) ~ B, ddpos)
abline(fm)
```

The last line could alternately be written as:

```
lines(fitted(fm) ~ B, ddpos)
```

In either case we get this figure:

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** We used this as the input:

```
dd <- structure(list(A = c(632364L, 144599L, 3715821L, 184524L, 1674L, 
0L, 8019L, 25992L, 0L, 0L, 19172040L), B = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
11L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 16L, 15L, 2L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Or transform the variable so that no value will give zero, and re-transform once you have the coefficients.